# Eclipse does not allow to add new virtual machine with API Level 15

Tags: android, eclipse

I am noobie to android development, and i want to create a virtual machine which has API level upper than 10. But eclipse does not allow me to do so. OK button remains disabled.When i change the API level 10, OK button is enabled. I am sure i have downloaded ARM EABI v7a System Image at API 17 and ADT Plugin correctly, and i couldn't find whether i have to make further configurations for different API levels. Any help would be appraciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Read this : https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing

Comment: I have replied for it on the first answer's comment.

Comment: go to help and click on check for update. its not a eclipse problem its SDK problem just because may be you are using SDK installer_r8-windows and API level 15 is not available in installer_r8-windows or something that you are using. its advisable that update your SDK first then go for platform otherwise SDk will not allow you to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have downloaded **ARM EABI v7a System Image** image for API 15 in the Android SDK Manager, it is in order to run Android API 15 in emulator.

It is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i have already installed it.To clear any confusion: Android SDK Manager shows ARM EABI v7a System Image as installed at API 17, under Android 4.2 (API 17). I think it must be sufficiant ?

Comment: OK, i have thougt that ARM EABI v7a System Image at API level 17 would be sufficient for API level 15. But it seems that i have to download accurate version which is API 15 in my case. Thank you.